# How to find a string in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = array("apple", "banana", "cap", "dog", etc..) up to 80 values.
```

and a string variable:

```
$str = "abc";
```

If I want to check whether this string (`$str`) exists in the array or not, I use the `preg_match` function, which is like this:

```
$isExists = preg_match("/$str/", $array);

if ($isExists) {
    echo "It exists";
} else {
    echo "It does not exist";
}
```

Is it the correct way? If the array grows bigger, will it be very slow? Is there any other method? I am trying to scaling down my database traffic.

And if I have two or more strings to compare, how can I do that?

Comment: can use two function in_array() and array_search()
Plaese see the tutorial prepared by me
http://braincybersolutions.com/php-tutorial/php-search-in-array/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```php
 bool in_array  ( mixed $needle  , array $haystack  [, bool $strict  ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 6):

If you just need an exact match, use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array)($str, $array) - it will be faster.

Another approach would be to use an associative array with your strings as the key, which should be logarithmically faster. Doubt you'll see a huge difference between that and the linear search approach with just 80 elements though.

If you *do* need a pattern match, then you'll need to loop over the array elements to use preg_match.

---

You edited the question to ask "what if you want to check for several strings?" - you'll need to loop over those strings, but you can stop as soon as you don't get a match...

```
$find=array("foo", "bar");
$found=count($find)>0; //ensure found is initialised as false when no terms
foreach($find as $term)
{
   if(!in_array($term, $array))
   {
        $found=false;
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

preg_match expects a string input not an array. If you use the method you described you will receive:

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in LOCATION on line X

You want in_array:

```
if ( in_array ( $str , $array ) ) {
    echo 'It exists';
} else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

Comment: the string like this $var "id1;id2";

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the built-in function in_array? (http://www.php.net/in_array)

preg_match will only work when looking for a substring in another string. ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php))

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one value you could either test every value separatly:

```
if (in_array($str1, $array) && in_array($str2, $array) && in_array($str3, $array) /* … */) {
    // every string is element of the array
    // replace AND operator (`&&`) by OR operator (`||`) to check
    // if at least one of the strings is element of the array
}
```

Or you could do an [intersection](http://docs.php.net/array_intersect) of both the strings and the array:

```
$strings = array($str1, $str2, $str3, /* … */);
if (count(array_intersect($strings, $array)) == count($strings)) {
    // every string is element of the array
    // remove "== count($strings)" to check if at least one of the strings is element
    // of the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function in_array() only detects complete entries if an array element. If you wish to detect a partial string within an array, each element must be inspected.

```
foreach ($array AS $this_string) {
  if (preg_match("/(!)/", $this_string)) {
    echo "It exists"; 
  }
}
```