# Search string in a multiple web pages with php

Tags: php

I need to search for a string and echo the webpage where the string had been found.
I have tried

```
 $lines=array();
 $fp=fopen('file.txt', 'r');
 while (!feof($fp)) {
   $line=fgets($fp);
   //process line however you like
   $line=trim($line);
   //add to array
   $lines[]=$line;
 }
 fclose($fp);
 $html = file($lines);
 $searchfor = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
 if(stripos($html, $searchfor)) {
   foreach ($lines as $linevalue) {
     echo "<table><tr><td>$linevalue</td></tr></table>";
   }
 }
```

It seams that `file_get_contents` doesn't allow arrays in it. I get the error
`Warning: file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given line 11`.

Expected output based on my example is to echo all the links from the file.txt(here i have the web pages that need to be crawled) that contain my link on those web pages. For example if mywebsite.com is found on the website1.com from line 1 from file.txt, it should echo `website1.com`. Please help me on this. I will appreciate the gesture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file()` takes a file path and reads it into an array of strings (the lines).
It's essentially the same as that loop you're doing first.

You can just do something like this

```
$files = array( 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt' );
$searchString = 'http://some-website-i-search.for';

foreach( $files as $file ) {

    $content = file_get_contents( $file );

    if( strpos( $content, $searchString ) !== false )
        echo "Found a match in $file!";
}
```

if that's what you're trying to achieve (Didn't test the code, sorry)

**Update:**

Here is the code so that you crawl all sites listed in a file with a URL on each line

```
$fileWithWebsitesOnEachLine = 'websites.txt';
$searchString = 'whatever you search for';

$sites = file( $fileWithWebsitesOnEachLine );

foreach( $sites as $site ) {

    $content = file_get_contents( $site );

    if( strpos( $content, $searchString ) )
        echo "Hey, I've found a match on $site!<br>";
}
```

Some explanation to this one.
Create a file called "websites.txt", put all links you want to check in it, one link on each line.
Then put whatever you search for in the `$searchString` variable

Then just run the script :)

Comment: The file is a single txt file that contains the web page links. I need smth like: FOREACH Access file->Access web page link-> Check if there is any link matching with mine on the webpage link from the file.txt -> If there are links then Print the web page link on the screen.

Comment: I've updated my solution with another code example that should do what you expect it to. Just read the code, I've named everything well I guess

Comment: You can't, only with libraries like CURL. Everything else will just return the HTML file that the server has set as the error file. It's plain HTML in any case here. You could check for the phrase "404" or something like that, but that isn't worth it since the error documents won't have the string you search for in it anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this problem a different way, but given what you've shown in the question, you should take a look at this question.

[How to find a string in an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555975/how-to-find-a-string-in-an-array-in-php)

What you have is an array of strings and you can search for your needle in that array.

**EDIT**
As requested, I'll edit my response, but I would do it the way Torben describes in his answer.

Something like this might be what you want.

```
<?php
$searchfor = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
$lines=array();
$fp=fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line=fgets($fp);
    // why not just check for the match right here
    if(stripos(trim($line), $searchfor)) {
        echo "<table><tr><td>$line</td></tr></table>";
    }
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Indeed, I have an array of strings, the thing is that i need to print on the screen the webpages that contain my link. I checked the question but did not understand exactly. Could you please guide me with an answer based on my example. Is much appreciated.

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my question. But I would probably take an approach more like what @Torben describes in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to mention is that you can replace the first 9 lines of your code with the 'file' function.  It reads the entire file into an array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

```
$html = file('file.txt');
```

In this case, however, you can actually leave it as a string and use 'file_get_contents' instead of turning it into an array at all.

```
$html = file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

Second thing is to use REGEX to find your patterns.  You can do a 'preg_match'/'preg_match_all' on your string or you can loop through your array and do a 'preg_match' on each line of your array, if you choose to use 'file' instead.

STRING

```
if (preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com/i', $html)) {
    // WE FOUND A MATCH - DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

ARRAY

```
foreach ($html AS $line) {
    if (preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com/i', $line)) {
        // WE FOUND A MATCH - DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```